# Laravel Cannot Decrypt Encrypted ID On Controller

Tags: laravel

I cannot decrypt the encrypted value on a controller after clicking on the submit button on my blade file below.

**Controller :**

```
public function edit($id)
{      
  $encrypted_id = encrypt($id);

  return view('my.blade.edit', compact('encrypted_id'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $decrypted_id = decrypt($id);

  dd($decrypted_id);
}
```

**Blade: (my.blade.edit)**

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['route.update', $encrypted_id ], 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}

{{ Form::button('Update', ['type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'update']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I am expecting an integer value on my `dd();` but I still getting an encrypted string.

Comment: Is `encrypt($id)` from `edit()` equals `$decrypted_id` if you compare them "as is"?

Comment: yes, for example, the variable ID is `123` then i will encrypt this, then it should get back to `123` after decrypting.

Comment: I meant, are already *hashed* strings equal?

Comment: ah, they are not. but I am still getting a long alphanumeric string.

Comment: This. You're decrypting wrong string.

Comment: the `decrypted_id` is 1/3 long of the `encrypted_id` though.

Comment: even if i put it on the hidden textbox, then decrypt it through `$decrypted_id = decrypt($request->hidden_textbox);` I am still getting the same result.

Comment: What about `post_max_size` in `php.ini`? Try to encode some id, put plain value as route parameter in the form and access it in `update()`

Comment: i got it, you are right, i am encrypting the wrong string. what really happened on my actual code is that I have encrypted the `id` twice. I just realized that the `id` on my `edit($id)` method is already encrypted.

Comment: maybe you can create an answer for me to accept. thank you for your help.

Comment: Should I? I just guided a little bit :)

Comment: well, you answered my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I've already written in the comments, first and simple is to check expected output and exact output.

So far we discovered, that value was sent to view isn't equal to value received in `update()` method.

`id` was encrypted twice, but we don't see two `encrypt()` calls in the code from the question. Probably some other code layer was making that.

Comment: thank you, i encrypted the ID twice, because the rows on my index already has an encrypted ID on it `<tr onclick="window.location='{{ route('route.edit', ['id' => encrypt($model->id)]) }}'">`